# Transformers training vs fine-tuning for a specific task

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, transformer-model

I am looking at the below tensorflow transformers implementation.

https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer

I am not sure I understood correctly. When initialising a transformers model it need to be trained on a lot of raw text in an unsupervised way so that it learns the language and then you can fit it to a particular task.

In this example, I am not sure if the training data is used to train the transformers model itself? It look like there is only one "fitting" procedure. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, I've also stumbled upon having to use transformer recently. Eventually I used pre-trained models from hugging face, e.g. an [English one for BERT](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased). You can easily fine-tune those.

Comment: Yeah I know how to fine tune those. Now I am trying fit one from scratch but from the tensorflow methodology I am not sure how to train it first so that it learn the language and then fine tuning it using transfer learning. I guess they only fit it once but I wanted to double check..

Answer (score 0):

The Transformer model was [originally proposed for machine translation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) in 2017, where it was directly trained on translation tasks. The additional step of pretraining Transformer-based models via self-supervised learning came later with models like GPT and BERT. The post you are looking at is an example of the former kind of approach.